# My SQL Login Function to Switch Frames Doesn't Work

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

My login function doesn't accept the correct username and password when inputted.

So, I'm trying to make a book management system using sqlite3 that has a two frames in a Tkinter window, f1 and f2. f1 contains a login function where if the correct username and password from the database are inputted, it moves to another frame using tkinter. However, it always goes for the "else" condition and says the username and password are incorrect.

```
def Login():
    Connect()
    Username=StringVar()
    Password=StringVar()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?",(Username.get(), Password.get(),))
    connection.commit()
    users = cursor.fetchall()
    print(users)
    connection.commit()
    if users is True:
        f2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        f1.pack_forget()
    else:
        label1=Label(root,text="Wrong username or password, please try again")
        label1.place(x=350,y=300)
        e2.delete(0, END)
```

It seems that I'm not getting anything back from the database with the SELECT command for some reason. Advice would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Username.get()` and `Password.get()` about a millisecond after creating those variables. There's no way for them to  have any value than their initial value, which will be an empty string since you don't give them an explicit default value.

Instead of creating the variables in the function, you should call the `get` methods of an `Entry` widget, assuming your program uses `Entry` widgets. Or, whatever code calls `Login` must also pass in the username and password. It's not clear from your question where you expect those values to come from.